# Is it possible to disable identityserver4's support for the implicit grant type?

Tags: identityserver4

I know that it is possible to control which grant types a client is allowed to use, but I want to have the discovery document exclude "implicit" from the grant_types_supported list. Just because identityserver4 supports implicit doesn't mean that my identity platform supports it. I know I can disallow all clients from using it, but I don't even want it to show in the discovery document.

I've researched this quite a bit, and while I can see that you can disable endpoints in the discovery document, I don't see anyway to alter the grant_types_supported list. I would have expected this to be documented [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/options.html#discovery), but I did not find anything. The wording of the paragraph on that page

*Allows enabling/disabling various sections of the discovery document, e.g. endpoints, scopes, claims, grant types etc.*

implies to me that it might be possible to enable/disable endpoints, scopes, claims, grant types, etc via this section of options, but it seems that it only controls including/excluding entire sections. For example, if you set Discovery.ShowGrantTypes to false, it would exclude the entire list from the document. I just want to remove the one item for implicit grant type.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't configurable in IdentityServer4. It's [hardcoded](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/ResponseHandling/Default/DiscoveryResponseGenerator.cs#L256) in the `DiscoveryResponseGenerator.CreateDiscoveryDocumentAsync` method.

The only solution I can see is to override this method, call into base, and then modify the resulting dictionary.